# Repeating linear gradient in IE

Tags: css

Having a hard time with this cross browser style for IE

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(68, 95, 127, 1), rgba(68, 95, 127, 1) 7px, rgba(68, 95, 127, 0.5 ) 7px, rgba(68, 95, 127, 0.5)10px
```

Can IE display a background this way?

Comment: which version of ie? This specific code doesn't work in chrome as well (you are missing a closing `)` at the end... Add an example that works in other browsers and explain exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @Dekel You're on to something. In some circumstances, Chrome and Firefox ignore the missing ) where IE11 doesn't. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3bqr7uz2/2/).

Comment: @Flignats Can you confirm that the problem is the missing ), then we can close this question.

Comment: Hey guys - thanks for the support and that missing ) - Unfortunately, that was a typo and the culprit wasn't the syntax, but it was white space.

Comment: @Dekel you are correct, Chrome does ignore the missing ) if not included, IE11 does not.